# python: relocation error - GLIBC/libc; hardware issue?

Tags: python, glibc

Python suddenly does not start anymore:

```
python: relocation error: python: symbol nl_l`nginfo, version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

OS is CentOS7, Python3.10 in conda environment.
I did a `yum update` a few days before, but python worked after that. Otherwise, no relevant messages in journalctl.

The symbol `` nl_l`nginfo `` (including the backtick) from the error message seems strange to me, I guess it should be `nl_langinfo`; could it be some hardware error (SSD)?

--

edit: I do have backups from that system. What files would be needed to checked to confirm some hardware issue (bit flip, etc)?

edit2: problem disappeared just like it appeared. I guess it could be problems with RAM? Some files were cached and got corrupted in RAM?

Comment: `yum update ...` from what repo(s)?  That looks like a `python` binary from a bad repo.

Comment: default CentOS repos + epel. Python did get updated, but only on the system itself and not within the conda environment.

Comment: What do you see if you run `strings -a .../python | grep nl_l`?  Maybe it's time to shut down and run `fsck` then?  Check your drive(s) for errors?  Uninstall and reinstall `python3`?

Comment: will try fsck and also run memtest - see edit above. Thanks for your help @AndrewHenle